# -bash: ./*: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I am attempting to write a BASH script to return the following information from CPUINFO using the following commands

- `./systemstat.sh  -r` to return the time along with total number of eth0 packets.
- `./systemstat -c` to return the vendor_id= and cpu MHz=.

When I use those commands, I recieve `-bash: ./systemstat.sh: No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't have `systemstat.sh` in your current directory `.`. The dot means the "current directory" or "working directory". If you do `ls .` you will notice that the script isn't there. For running this script you should either use:

- the full path `/path/to/script/systemstat.sh`
- copying them to a bin directory `cp systemstat.sh /usr/local/bin/` then run **without the dot**: `systemstat.sh`
- Or adding the directory where the script is to the path `PATH=/path/to/script:$PATH` and then execute the script without the dot.
- or move your working directory to were the script is `cd /path/to/script && ./systemstat.sh`